# how to customize jTable header column font size in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I tried to change `jtable` header font size in `Netbeans`. but couldn't yet. anyway the table rows font size is changed successfully.

**Here is the way I used:**

[image: ?]

**The output after changes:**

[image: ?]

**Problem :** The Header font size is not changed. but I want to change that also. so pls help me how to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use the `UIManager` and replace the default `Font` with the one you want

```
Font font = UIManager.getFont("TableHeader.font");
font = font.deriveFont(48f);
UIManager.put("TableHeader.font", font);
```

Which will replace the font used by all the tables in the system

[image: Column Headers]

Another way is to provide a custom `TableCellRenderer` for the columns you want to change, it's a little more work, but provides more flexibility as you can decide where you want to apply them.  You could wrap this inside your own custom `JTableHeader`, but I'm just providing some basic ideas.

```
public class HeaderRenderer implements UIResource, TableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer original;

    public HeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                                                                 Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                                                                                                 int column) {
        Component comp = original.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        comp.setFont(comp.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        return comp;
    }

}
```

Which is installed using something like...

```
HeaderRenderer header = new HeaderRenderer(table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer());
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
columnModel.getColumn(0).setHeaderRenderer(header);
```

And produces something like...

[image: Custom Column Header]

[Credit to Kleopatra for this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175997/how-to-make-the-defaulttablemodel-table-header-bold)

The long and short of it is, you're going to have to get your hands dirty and write some code, the form editor won't do everything for you

Comment: plz help me this question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779352/code-error-in-set-data-into-rows-in-jtable-java