# Set tooltip for cells in jTable without overriding getToolTipText()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making gui with the NetBeans GUI Builder(Swing) and need to set different tooltips for each cells in the header. The problem is that jTable is generated automatically, so I can't override its methods.

Is there any possibility to do it without the overriding `getToolTipText()`?

Comment: You can supply your own renderer for the `JTableHeader`

Comment: Maybe start by having a look at [`JTableHeader#setDefaultRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html#setDefaultRenderer-javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer-) - [as a conceptual example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775868/how-to-customize-jtable-header-column-font-size-in-netbeans/41776160#41776160)

Comment: `The problem is that jTable is generated automatically` - The IDE should not be used to generate your code, only as an aid to help you compile and debug. Spend your time learning how to use Java/Swing, not how to use and IDE. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Specifying Tool Tips for Column Headers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#headertooltip) for a working example to get you started.

Comment: @camickr, i agree with you, but i am new in Swing, so it's a little bit difficult for me now) And I've already read this article before to ask the question) Anyway, thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this sort of thing is to add a subclass which extends the **MouseMotionAdapter** and a method to your code to carry out the task for you. Simply place the following SubClass code below the end of your main Class.

```
class JTableColumnHeaderToolTips extends MouseMotionAdapter {
    TableColumn curCol;
    // Create a Map to hold the Header Column 
    // index value and the tooltip related to 
    // it.
    Map headerColumnTips = new HashMap();

    // Method to Set tips into Map.
    public void setHeaderColumnToolTip(TableColumn column, String tooltip) {
        if (tooltip == null) {
            headerColumnTips.remove(column);
        } 
        else {
            headerColumnTips.put(column, tooltip);
        }
    }

    // Override the Header's mouseMoved event so as 
    // to display the appropriate tooltip for whatever
    // column the mouse pointer is currently on.
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader) event.getSource();
        JTable table = header.getTable();
        TableColumnModel colModel = table.getColumnModel();
        int colIndex = colModel.getColumnIndexAtX(event.getX());
        TableColumn column = null;
        if (colIndex >= 0) {
            column = colModel.getColumn(colIndex);
        }
        if (column != curCol) {
            header.setToolTipText((String) headerColumnTips.get(column));
            curCol = column;
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this method **setJTableColumnToolTips()** somewhere within your main Class:

```
private void SetJTableHeaderColumnToolTips(JTable table, String[] columnToolTips) {
    JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();

    // See the JTableColumnHeaderToolTips SubClass. 
    JTableColumnHeaderToolTips toolTips = new JTableColumnHeaderToolTips();
    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        TableColumn columnIndex = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col);
        toolTips.setHeaderColumnToolTip(columnIndex, columnToolTips[col]);
    }
    tableHeader.addMouseMotionListener(toolTips);
}
```

To use this method you might do it this way:

```
// Provide the Tooltips you want for
// each column within a String Array.
String[] columnToolTips = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "The person's address",
            "The person's phone number",
            "The person's age",
            "The person's salary"};

// Set your desired ToolTips to the Header Column cells
setJTableHeaderColumnToolTips(recordsTable, columnToolTips);
```

Comment: @Kryvich `thank you very mush for such quick and full answer!` - and look at all the extra work you need to do just to get around the fact that you are using an IDE.